# Refresh iframe when refreshing page

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

i have web page it has a page header content like main menu,logo and so..on..

and in iframe i am loading the side menu and content. while loading the web page i am using an empty home page to display. after some time in mid of some page while refresing the page it reloads the home page. But i need to display the page that i am using as a current page

code is

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 100%" height="115px">
                <div>
                    <uc1:MainMenu ID="ucMainMenu" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                
            <td>
                <iframe src="HomePage.aspx" runat="server" width="1250px" height="675px" id="ifSideMenu"
                    frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

in that iframe deafult page is Homepage.aspx,it is empty page. When i clicked the sub menu it loads the content like AddMaster.aspx. When i refresh the page it loads Homepage.aspx, but i need to display AddMaster.aspx

help me

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but it does not sound sane. I would advise against using iframes at all. But if you really want help, you'll have to be way more specific. Provide code, URLs or screenshots, etc.

Comment: during refresh the initial url for the blank page has not been updated by you, so on refresh it picks up the same value. Some code on how you doing this can shed some light

Comment: Do you mean by any chance that you want to remember the last page user clicked in the menu and show this page when user is reloading, instead of showing the default homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer for this question.

It may help for others.

Add the below code in HomePage.aspx and other pages that are going to load in the iframe

```
Session["CurrentPage"] = Request.RawUrl.ToString().Replace(Request.ApplicationPath.ToString() + @"/", "");
```

in Main Page in page load event.

```
if (Session["CurrentPage"] == null)
    Session["CurrentPage"] = "Exit_Tracker.aspx";

ifSideMenu.Attributes["src"] = Session["CurrentPage"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will help u to refresh the iframe only.. not the whole web page. but., i dont understand your que clearly brother.

```
<IFRAME id="frame1" src="http://www.google.com/"  runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshiframe()
    {
        parent.frame1.location.href="http://www.google.com/"
        setTimeout("refreshiframe()",3000);
    }
    </script>

<body  onload="refreshiframe();">
```